# Ubuntu getrandom(2) set flag GRND_RANDOM

Tags: server

If I call random_int(1,100000) from PHP it will syscall getrandom(2) from Ubuntu to retrieve random numbers. http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php

getrandom(2) uses /dev/urandom by default which I do not want since I have a hardware random number generator feeding /dev/random. The Ubuntu manual says If GRND_RANDOM bit is set, then random bytes are drawn from the /dev/random pool instead of the /dev/urandom pool.
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man2/getrandom.2.html

I just can't figure out how to set the flag GRND_RANDOM. Is there a configuration file I need to edit? Where?

Comment: If your hardware RNG feeds /dev/random, it feeds /dev/urandom too. Linux will never provide worse answers if it can provide better ones.

Comment: I think what you are saying is /dev/random & /dev/urandom/ share the same entropy so the hardware random number generator should feed the entropy and thus both.  As long as I don't run the entropy pool down it really won't matter if I fix Ubuntu to use /dev/random.  Best answer yet but I know there is a way to default to /dev/random/

Comment: Even if you do run the entropy down, it still won't matter. And you don't want `/dev/random` because it blocks even when perfect entropy is available.

Comment: I would prefer that it blocks if entropy is down for my application.

Comment: Ahh, you want Holy water and ordinary water just won't do.